# How to fix corrupted (non-Explorer/system) icons in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-office, icons, adobe-reader

It seems like Windows XP doesn't recognize default icons of many applications in my old Dell machine e.g. Skype, Windows Live Messenger, Adobe Reader, Microsoft Office 2003. Though I can open all those applications, the most annoying part is that all files associated with them don't have icons too and I cannot get their types by glancing at their icons. Is there a way to fix this without reinstalling Windows and all softwares?

FYI I have tried TweakUI and cleared icon cache but it didn't work.

Comment: did you reboot after clearing the icon cache? Have you tried safe mode to fix it?

Comment: I rebooted but it didn't work still.
Did you mean I should try clearing the icon cache in safe mode?

Comment: Yes, maybe that works? I think it's worth a try.

Comment: No, it still doesn't work. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Several years down the line...but if this is still affecting you, see the answer to this question: (http://superuser.com/questions/1065358/application-icons-corrupted-in-explorer/1065464#1065464).

Answer (score 1):

You can delete the `Iconcache.db` file in the application data location and restart machine to fix the corrupted Windows XP icons. It will rebuild it while reboot.

default location of `Iconcache.db`is in (hidden file)

`C:\Documents and Settings\<username>\Local Settings\Application Data`

Comment: This has not helped me with the same issue, but I know several people on forums report this working.

Answer (score 1):

You always can try the repair installation option that most installers have. They will restore the icons and the registry associations.

Answer (score 0):

Try to restore the default association for ico files you can find a reg file that do this [here](http://www.dougknox.com/xp/fileassoc/xp_ico_file_assoc_fix.zip)

Comment: I will try this as soon as I can put my hands on that machine. Hope it works. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tried it but didn't work still.

Answer (score 0):

Changing your desktop colour depth and then changing it back again (i.e. 32-bit to 24-bit and back) should also rebuild them.

Comment: I have tried that too. But it didn't work. Thanks anyway.